# System.FinalException: Record is read-only while giving Apex Sharing

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a OWD, `Case` is `Private` and `Payment1` and `Payment2` has lookup relationship with the Case object. OWD for Payment1 and Payment2 also Private.

When Case is submitted by User i.e Original requestor, he should get `READ` only access on the Case and `Payment1 and Payment2` object. Once case is Submitted, we need to make a Queue as the owner of the Case and Payment1 and Payment2.

Case is a single form which has Payment1 and Case fields. When Case is created then Case record will insert first then Payment1.

When Payment1 record inserted, I need make Payment1 owner same like Case Owner and I need to give READ access to Original requestor.

I did like below, but I get the below error.

> 10:51:49.14 (1226996739)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[60]|System.FinalException: Record is read-only
>   10:51:49.14 (1227129014)|FATAL_ERROR|System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Here is the code

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
    MakeOwnerDynamically.checkOwner(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
    MakeOwnerDynamically.changePayment1Owner(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
}
```

Here is the logic I implemented, but dont know when to create the Payment1_Share record

Here is the another code

```
public static void checkOwner(List<Payment1__c> newPayment1, Map<Id, Payment1__c> oldPayment1Map){  
    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Payment1__c pay1 : newPayment1){
        caseIdSet.add(pay1.Case__c);
    }

    Map<Id,Case> caseMap = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id,RecordType.DeveloperName,OwnerId,
                                            FROM Case 
                                            WHERE Id IN :caseIdSet]);

    changePayment1Owner(newPayment1, caseMap);
    System.debug('~~~~~~~~ NoOfExtenpay1onClass calling end ~~~~~~~~~');
}

public static void changePayment1Owner(List<Payment1__c> newPayment1, Map<Id,Case> caseMap){
    List<Payment1__c> pay1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst = new List<Payment1__c>();

    for(Payment1__c pay1 : newPayment1){
        System.debug('CASE_OWNERID : '+caseMap.get(pay1.Case__c).OwnerId + ', pay1_OWNERID : '+pay1.OwnerId);

        if(caseMap.get(pay1.Case__c).OwnerId != pay1.OwnerId){
            pay1.OwnerId = caseMap.get(pay1.Case__c).OwnerId;
            pay1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst.add(pay1);
        }
    }
    System.debug('FINAL_pay1_DETAILS :: '+pay1InfoToUpdateOwnerLst);       
}
```

My Payment1_Share logic

```
Payment1__Share pi1Share = new Payment1__Share();
pi1Share.ParentId = pi.Id;
pi1Share.RowCause = 'Manual';
pi1Share.AccessLevel = 'Read';
pi1Share.UserOrGroupId = pi.CreatedById;
pi1ShareList.add(pi1Share);
```

**TWO CHALLENGES:?**

- I cant create Share record in Before Insert.
- I cant create findout if the old owner and Owner of the Case is same or  different in After triiger..

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

From the `Apex Developer Guide` on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

When you call `MakeOwnerDynamically.changePayment1Owner`, you are updating record values before they are saved to the database. Move the functionality to your before trigger.

Comment: Right.. But in before trigger logic I wont be able to insert Payment1_Share..that should be developed in After update ? Please see updates above

Comment: Yes, creating other records should go in the after trigger.

Comment: if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) - Will be fine ? But I dont see its calling my required method... But how can I find who was the original Requestor in isAfter?